# How can one modify the ClientId of a CompositeControl, eliminate rendering of said ID, without impacting ChildControls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have a composite control that renders:

```
<span id="controlID">
   <span id="controID_propertyID">
   <input id="controID_inputID">
```

The issue I'm having is when I try to reference the AssociatedControlID so as to bind a label to the input, I wind up with a:

```
 <label for="controlID">
```

Where I want:

```
 <label for="controlID_inputID">
```

I've tried:

```
    public override string ClientID
    {
        get
        {
            return _input.ClientID;
        }
    }
```

But then the span and input have the same id.

```
<span id="controID_inputID">
   <span id="controID_propertyID">
   <input id="controID_inputID">
```

Then I tried:

```
    public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
    }

    public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
```

But this kills the uniqueness of the Property Span as well, which I want.

```
<span>
   <span id="propertyID">   // I still want:  <span id="controlID_propertyID">
   <input id="controID_inputID">
```

Is there a way I can achieve what I want without having to switch the CompositeControl to be a WebControl. I would also like to avoid injecting codeblocks like:

```
 <label for="<%=control.ClientID%>_input">
```

Or any similar work-arounds via code-behind, literals, or whatnot.

Comment: How is your control defined? Without seeing the code, I can't help you...

Comment: @Ben public abstract class SaidControl: CompositeControl Are there other details needed? I can redefine it as need be, but not into a WebControl.

Comment: In your override for RenderBeginTag, you can call writer.AddAttribute to set the ID and other properties.  [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5ahks8.aspx).

Comment: you should provide the code for your CompositeControl class or at least the markup you are using with. It is not clear what you are using and how.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing ClientIDMode for your control - there could be an option to make ids for child controls "predictable".
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.100).aspx

One more thing: using AssociatedControlID, which control do you pass here? Looks like you're passing the parent itself, not child one.

Comment: I'm returning the ID of the child control: return _input.ClientID; ClientIDMode looks nice, but I'm also working in 3.5. This appears to be a 4.0+ technology?

Comment: Yes, it is. ))
Maybe try some sort of this:
Control MyInput = MyCompositeControl.FindControl("MyInputID");
return MyInput.ClientID;

Comment: _input is the child control, and I don't seem to be able to have access to ClientIDMode. MSDN doesn't seem to offer it for other versions. I also don't want to have to manually pull the ClientID out of the control, I wanted the composite control to provide that data so that labels could be bound in the mark-up vs pro grammatically.

Comment: If you want to somehow pass the ClientID to the label, you must know the ClientID at the moment. As I see, there is two options:
1. You pass ClientID property to your label - the thing you're trying to avoid, am I right?
2. You watch rendered markup and decide, that the ID you could see in browser is the one you need, so simply put it in your source for asp.net markup.
The second variant is worse, because you actually cannot be sure, that the string you've inserted as ClientID always will match the real one. For instance, your web page could be converted to control, or you upgrade to .Net 4.0.